# Count all objects and variables in use

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Is it possible to count created objects and variables in javascript?

I am using Google Chrome to analyse my web app. But to debug and find the objects that causes "Memory Leak" is not so easy (at least for me). So I want to know all objects and variables that are created on the current page so I can know if they are removed.

Comment: Please post some code; we can't help you if we don't know what you're doing!

Comment: I don't really think this is possible.

Comment: The thing to do is identify page behavior/activity that causes overall memory use to go up.

Comment: For memory leaks there's the "profiler" in devtools.

Comment: @Mooseman this is really not about codes. This is a general question

Comment: @elclanrs yes, I know "Heap Snapshots" but there are millions of results. I can't follow them well enought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that in Chrome (or any other major browser). You *can* use Chrome's "memory" page (chrome://memory/) to get *some* idea what's going on, but it's not down to the object level, and it's important to understand that garbage collection does *not* happen synchronously or immediately. The browser / JavaScript engine may well allocate memory, use it for some JavaScript objects, and then later correctly understand that those objects aren't used anymore, but keep the memory handy for future use.

Instead, what you can do is study how JavaScript works in detail, which tells you what will (usually) be kept in memory, and why. Understand [how closures work](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*, and understand how IE doesn't handle circular references between DOM elements and JavaScript objects well (specifically, it doesn't clean them up well when nothing refers to either of them anymore, which is otherwise not normally a problem). And in general, don't worry too much about it until/unless you have a specific issue to address. (Which absolutely happens, but not as much as people sometimes think.)

Comment: I just saw on Google Chrome's Timeline-Plugin: when I start recording the page its starts from 20MB - 40MB and then i am switching to other page its beeing 20MB - 47MB and I am switching back and it is jumping from 47 MB to 63 MB. is this normal? I.E. the memory should be cleaned when I press F5 ?

Comment: or a short question: What happens when we refresh the page (F5) ? does the memory reset?

Comment: @DavidB.: I don't honestly know, but I wouldn't expect it to. (And remember this will all be **very** browser-specific.) Chrome runs each tab in a process. If the process has allocated memory, it probably will tend to keep it (for a brief period, anyway) in order to reuse it, rather than immediately returning it to the OS, since getting it and returning it are (relatively) expensive.

Comment: Thank you T.J. Crowder, I will try to understand better "how closures work".